# Get colors from stacked plot

Tags: python, plot, plotly, plotly-express

I have this Plotly plot (blurred sensitive data):
[image: plot]

which I got using `fig = px.bar(stacked, x='Data', y='Kwota', color='Kategoria')` from `plotly_express`.

Is there a way to obtain the colors which were automatically used for categories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [this recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59806427/1185254):

> [...] the default sequence comes from `layout.colorway` in the active
>   template.
>
> In the default template called `plotly` this is the sequence available
>   under `px.colors.qualitative.Plotly`.
>
> This sequence is `['#636EFA', '#EF553B', '#00CC96', '#AB63FA',
>   '#FFA15A', '#19D3F3', '#FF6692', '#B6E880', '#FF97FF', '#FECB52']`

Comment: I understood your question more along the lines of being able to read that information out of your plot *directly*. But I was planning to link the information from nicolaskruchten (since I was the one to raise that question) to my original answer here too. In any case I'm glad you got the information you needed.

Comment: @vestland Oops, sorry for the poor phrasing. And thank you for posting an answer anyway!