# Plotly: What color cycle does plotly express follow?

Tags: python, plotly

I would think that the default color cycle would be (some variants of) `['blue', 'red', 'green', 'purple', 'orange']` like in the plot below:

**Plot 1:**

[image]

**Code 1:**

```
import plotly
import plotly.express as px

gapminder = px.data.gapminder()
gapminder2007=gapminder.query("year==2007")
px.scatter(gapminder2007, x='gdpPercap', y='lifeExp', color="continent")
```

At least that *seems* to be the order of the cycle since omitting `Oceania` from the continents will give you this:

[image]

Now the order of the remaining colors are the same except for the last orange looking one (just showing that the application of the colors are not aribtrary).

I thought this would be possible to retrieve using `plotly.colors.DEFAULT_PLOTLY_COLORS` which will give you:

```
['rgb(31, 119, 180)',
 'rgb(255, 127, 14)',
 'rgb(44, 160, 44)',
 'rgb(214, 39, 40)',
 'rgb(148, 103, 189)',
 'rgb(140, 86, 75)',
 'rgb(227, 119, 194)',
 'rgb(127, 127, 127)',
 'rgb(188, 189, 34)',
 'rgb(23, 190, 207)']
```

But those colors are ordered like `['blue', 'orange', 'green', 'red']...`

So, what color cycle *does* plotly express follow when setting for `color="continent"` in `px.scatter(gapminder2007, x='gdpPercap', y='lifeExp', color="continent")`?

I tried looking under `help(px.colors)` too, but that didn't give much:

> Help on module plotly.express.colors in plotly.express:
>
> NAME
> plotly.express.colors
>
> DATA
> DEFAULT_PLOTLY_COLORS = ['rgb(31, 119, 180)', 'rgb(255, 127, 14)', 'rg...
> PLOTLY_SCALES = {'Blackbody': [[0, 'rgb(0,0,0)'], [0.2, 'rgb(230,0,0)'...
> absolute_import = _Feature((2, 5, 0, 'alpha', 1), (3, 0, 0, 'alpha', 0...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This doc page covers discrete color sequences: https://plot.ly/python/discrete-color/ and mentions that the default sequence comes from `layout.colorway` in the active template.

In the default template called `plotly` this is the sequence available under `px.colors.qualitative.Plotly`.

This sequence is `['#636EFA', '#EF553B', '#00CC96', '#AB63FA', '#FFA15A', '#19D3F3', '#FF6692', '#B6E880', '#FF97FF', '#FECB52']`