# How to visualize through time a data that is quantitative or qualitative, but never both?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plotly, plotly-python

I have a csv file where some rows have words, and some have numbers. Something like :

```
         column1   column2  column3 
date      2019      2020      2021
color     blue      blue     yellow
velocity    1        22        3 
power       4        2         1
```

And I need to visualize it in a plot that allows me to visually search for patterns between all the attributes (color, velocity, power) trough time. But all plotly [plots](https://plotly.com/python/line-charts/) I've found only allow me to track quantitative or qualitative values alone, not together.
I cant even visualize in my head how a plot would have to be to allow this ... The only way I can think of, is to transpose each qualitative value to a new row, and add an arbitrary  and constant number to it, like :

```
       column1   column2  column3 
date      2019      2020      2021
blue       100       100       0  
yellow      0        0        100
velocity    1        22        3 
power       4        2         1
```

So in a line plot, for example,  there would be a straight line at the top indicating which qualitative value is happening, while all others would be at the bottom.  And I guess it could be colored according to the row index(date, color, velocity, power), allowing me to identify it visually. But I'm quite sure there is a better way.

Any plot library is acceptable, although plotly is preferential, because its easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Your data as presented is four factors.  So you can use a **scatter** for **x,y,size & color**
- **color** is an obvious choice for qualitative.  Others can also be qualitative by using categorical data types as well.

```
import io
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""         column1   column2  column3 
date      2019      2020      2021
color     blue      blue     yellow
velocity    1        22        3 
power       4        2         1  """), sep="\s+").T

df["date"] = df["date"].astype(int)
df["velocity"] = df["velocity"].astype(int)
df["power"] = df["power"].astype(int)

fig = px.scatter(df, x="date", y="velocity", color="color", size="power")
fig.update_layout(xaxis={"tickformat":"d"})
```

[image]

Comment: And what if there is 10 qualitative values, instead of just one ? Maybe the simple way would be to create two diferent plots ? one for the qualitative data and one for the quantitative ?

Comment: more values simple - it will just work.  if you mean more factors / dimensions - for example with financial data, **asset type**, **trade type**, **market**, **exchange**, **underlying** along with **price**, **quantity** clear you need to limit to number of factors that can be represented in a chart and provide options for choosing other dimensions

Answer (score 0):

A standard `px.scatter(df, x="date", y="velocity", color="color", size="power")` seems to be working just fine. But if your setup is not only a representation of a more complicated real world case, I would  suggest a little tweak so that the name in the legend does not *say* `'yellow'` but *display* `'red'`, which is exactly what is going to happen because `color` in `px.scatter(color ='color')` does not actually *assign* a color, but rather a categorical variable to which a [color sequence will be applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59732422/plotly-what-color-cycle-does-plotly-express-follow). And I suspect that simultanously showing ***and*** naming the color in the legend is a bit superflous. Anyway, I hope you'll find this useful:

```
fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(marker_color = t.name, name=''))
```

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': {'column1': 2019, 'column2': 2020, 'column3': 2021},
                     'color': {'column1': 'blue', 'column2': 'blue', 'column3': 'yellow'},
                     'velocity': {'column1': 1, 'column2': 22, 'column3': 3},
                     'power': {'column1': 4, 'column2': 2, 'column3': 1}})

fig = px.scatter(df, x="date", y="velocity", color="color", size="power")
f = fig.full_figure_for_development(warn=False)

fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(marker_color = t.name, name=''))

fig.show()
```